# ios : Nullpointer exception

Tags: ios, animation, crash

I got the following code:

```
- (void) hide_waiting_activity
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];        
        self.waiting_view.alpha = 0;
        self.waiting_label.alpha = 0;
        self.activity_indicator.alpha = 0;
    } [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The problem: It crashes sometimes and sometimes not. If it crashes the console output looks something like this:

> 2013-02-07 18:16:21.658 driver[5912:907]
>   -[NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariable count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd3aea0 2013-02-07 18:16:21.679 driver[5912:907]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariable count]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x1dd3aea0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x342e03e7 0x3bfd1963 0x342e3f31 0x342e264d 0x3423a208 0x34c90d5b 0x34c9a6c3 0x34c9a56f 0x34c9a781
>   0x34c9acf1 0x34c99d6b 0x34c9ac31 0x34c92393 0x34c94f01 0x34c95ed7
>   0x34c9ecab 0x36527519 0x36527689 0x365277ab 0x3652791f 0x36527acf
>   0x34c95997 0x36527a41 0x3652aad1 0x3652d0d9 0x3652cfe3 0x34226acd
>   0x3652cf97 0x34226acd 0x3652cf97 0x34226acd 0x3652cf97 0x34226acd
>   0x3652cf97 0x34226acd 0x3652cf97 0x34226acd 0x3652cf97 0x34226acd
>   0x3652cf97 0x34226acd 0x3652cf97 0x34c95997 0x36526f3d 0x361623dd
>   0x35e9e513 0x35e9e0b5 0x35e9efd9 0x35e9e9c3 0x35e9e7d5 0x35e9e639
>   0x342b5941 0x342b3c39 0x342b3f93 0x3422723d 0x342270c9 0x37e0533b
>   0x361432b9 0xd3871 0xc29d8) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing
>   an exception

the corresponding stacktrace looks like this:
[image]

or something like this:

> driver(5930,0x3df85b78) malloc: *** error for object 0x1e565990:
>   pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug (lldb)

Then the stacktrace looks like
[image]

I'm completely clueless. Has anybody got an idea? I'm using ios 6.1.

Update:
Commenting the inner nested brackets does not change anything:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
        //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        //[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
        self.waiting_view.alpha = 0;
        self.waiting_label.alpha = 0;
        self.activity_indicator.alpha = 0;
    } [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Update 2:
After removing the curly brackets the app still crashes as decribed.

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
        self.waiting_view.alpha = 0;
        self.waiting_label.alpha = 0;
        self.activity_indicator.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Update 3:
This is the complete code that contain any of the affected ui elements in the hide_waiting_activity:

MainNavigationController.h

```
//Waiting overlay
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIActivityIndicatorView* activity_indicator;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView* waiting_view;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel* waiting_label;
```

MainNavigationController.m

```
@implementation MainNavigationController

@synthesize activity_indicator;
@synthesize waiting_view;
@synthesize waiting_label;

...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create a transparent waiting indicator view that is shown to the user while the app is working in background
    waiting_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 64.f /* top navigation bar is 64.f */, 320, 480 )];
    [waiting_view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Main_Menu_Background.png"]];

    waiting_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.activity_indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [self.activity_indicator setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.activity_indicator startAnimating];
    self.activity_indicator.center = CGPointMake( 160.f, (240.f-64.f) );
    [waiting_view addSubview:activity_indicator];

    waiting_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 110.f, (240.f-64.f)+30.f, 100.f, 16.f)];
    waiting_label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.f];
    waiting_label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    waiting_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    waiting_label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    waiting_label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Please_Wait_Text", @"");
    [waiting_view addSubview:waiting_label];

    [self.view addSubview:waiting_view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.activity_indicator];
    self.waiting_view.hidden = YES;
    self.activity_indicator.hidden = YES;
...
}

- (void) show_waiting_activity
{
    if( self.waiting_view.alpha == 1 && self.waiting_view.hidden == NO )
        return;

    self.waiting_view.hidden = NO;
    self.activity_indicator.hidden = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.2];        
        self.waiting_view.alpha = 1;
        self.waiting_label.alpha = 1;
        self.activity_indicator.alpha = 1;
    } [UIView commitAnimations];
}



- (void) hide_waiting_activity
{    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
        self.waiting_view.alpha = 0;
        self.waiting_label.alpha = 0;
        self.activity_indicator.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I'm asking myself where in this code the ui elements could be destroyed in these .5 seconds?

Comment: Can you take out the nested brackets and see what happens?

Comment: Actually, what I meant was remove the curly braces after `[UIView beginAnimations...]` and before `[UIView commitAnimations]`

Comment: I updated my question again

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the code you pasted - the problem is what's happening to the views it's referencing after the animation starts (somewhere else in your code). If the animation is running for 0.5 seconds, all those views *must* be alive still for the next 0.5 seconds.

So, your choices for views that are not living long enough: self, self.waiting_view, self.waiting_label, self.activity_indicator.

Comment: Thanks I gave an Update 3 in my question.